# SAPUI5 Chart 50053 incomplete dimension binding

Tags: charts, sapui5

Experimenting with charts for the first time, trying to setup a simple chart here which is simply based on 3 values from the table seen in the snapshot below (chart positioned exactly below): ​Type ID, Avg Gross Turnaround Time (1st occurence), Avg Net Turnaround Time (1st occurence) and (as visible) I get the aforementioned error.

[Chart Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfLCp.jpg)

Of course, before posting I had a look to similar questions and in all cases the solution was the same, that the values provided in the measures/dimensions of the dataset must be the same (makes sense) with the ones provided with the FeedItems method. Problem is that I have them right. Thought about a syntax error within the dataset/feed definitions (eg, single instead of double quotes). Tried numerous combinations so far, result always the same, so I ended up leaving the only syntax that wasn't giving me blue warnings in the editor. (Extremely short) controller code follows below. Does this ring any bells?
​

​Regards

​Greg

```
            var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idStackedChart");
            oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
                plotArea: {
                    colorPalette: d3.scale.category20().range(),
                    dataLabel: {
                        showTotal: true
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Stacked Bar Chart"
                }
            });
            var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
                dimensions: [{
                    name: "Type",
                    value: "{AgrTypeid}"
                }],

                measures: [{
                    name: "Gross Turnaround",
                    value: "{Yr1Avggta}"
                }, {
                    name: "Net Turnaround",
                    value: "{Yr1Avgnta}"
                }],

                data: {
                    path: "/Agreement_Summary"
                }
            });
            oVizFrame.setDataset(oDataset);

            oVizFrame.setModel();

            var oFeedValueAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                    uid: "valueAxis",
                    type: "Measure",
                    values: ["Yr1Avggta"]
                }),
                oFeedValueAxis1 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                    uid: "valueAxis",
                    type: "Measure",
                    values: ["Yr1Avgnta"]
                }),
                oFeedCategoryAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                    uid: "categoryAxis",
                    type: "Dimension",
                    values: ["AgrTypeid"]
                });

            oVizFrame.addFeed(oFeedValueAxis);
            oVizFrame.addFeed(oFeedValueAxis1);
            oVizFrame.addFeed(oFeedCategoryAxis);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it works a little different, here's the correct feed code:

```
var oFeedValueAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
    uid: "valueAxis",
    type: "Measure",
    values: ["Type"]    //--> should be same as Measure name
}),
oFeedValueAxis1 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
    uid: "valueAxis",
    type: "Measure",
    values: ["Gross Turnaround"]  //--> should be same as Measure name
}),
oFeedCategoryAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
    uid: "categoryAxis",
    type: "Dimension",
    values: ["Net Turnaround"]     //--> should be same as Dimension name
});
```